# The EVM throws an error "invalid opcode 0x1c"

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, golang

I have written a simple smart contract that allows to store a string, and I'am trying to use go-ethereum(which is similar to web3j).
When I execute a transaction, I have this error

```
    VM returned with error err="invalid opcode 0x1c"
```

I am testing on a local network that I have developed using geth nodes.
When I tested the same smart contract using remix (connecting remix to my local network), everything went right and the smart contracts executes fine.

Comment: Hi there. _"I have written a simple smart contract"_ - we'll need to see the contract code. We'll also need further information about your environment. How many nodes are you using? Which client version? Have you made any alterations to the client code? You mentioned Geth nodes, but tagged the question with Quorum. Can you clarify if you're using Quorum or not?

Comment: I'am using geth client, qurum uses these client to interact the blcockhain and it adds other features like constellation nodes for security.
I'am using a 5 node network.
this is my environment:
Version: 1.8.18-stable
Git Commit: aa74813e330f8f7782df629d5ec8317c81739827
Quorum Version: 2.2.3
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1337
Go Version: go1.10
Operating System: linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That opcode is a recent addition to geth in the Constantinople release.
You need to add the following to your genesis to enable Constantinople:

```
"constantinopleBlock":0,
```